# a database for storing html

Tags: html, database

Which open source databases are fit for storing html? I am looking for a database that at the minimum would support XPath queries, be scalable etc.

Comment: Any database that can store a string value?!?!?! ...

Comment: XPath queries. That's interesting. Why do you need that and how do you plan on doing such a query.

Comment: what's the problem with RDBMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to pre-process the HTML to normalize it into XHTML format using tools such as [TagSoup](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup), then you could use an open source XML database, such as [eXist](http://exist-db.org/).

Answer (score 3):

[NoSQL](http://nosql-database.org/)